# Static html pages run from file system instead of built-in web-server

Tags: intellij-idea, localhost, intellij-13

I'm running Intellij 13 Ultimate. I'm trying to open a web page I'm working on, and it's opened from the file system:

```
file:///Users/<username>/dev/index.html
```

Instead of something like:

```
http://localhost:<port>/index.html
```

Thing is, other projects run as expected and I can't figure out what's misconfigured in this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

How do you *open* the page?

If you open your HTML file inside IntelliJ and go to `Run > Run xxx.html` (or `Debug`), a localhost page should be opened. If it isn't, check your Run Configuration (`Run > Edit Configurations`) and check the `URL` field.

`View > Open in Browser` should also work as expected.

Comment: The url looks good and also through "Open in Browser" I get the same thing :/

Comment: Ok, I figured this out - my files are under src/main/web/app. If I put them under 'src' it works. Although I don't understand why that's the case.

Comment: Just had this issue and changing the project location to the 'src' directory worked for me as well. Thx, Avi!